# How to connect html fields in django forms

Tags: html, django, forms

This is my bootstrap html page I am trying to establish the connection between models and html fields.
contact.html

{% load static from staticfiles %}

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">

      <head>
        <style>
          body{
            background: url('{% static "img/new4.jpg" %}') no-repeat center fixed;
            - webkit- background: cover;
            - moz - background: cover;
            - o - background: cover;
                  background-size: cover;
          }

          </style>


        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">

        <title>Personality Leading.com</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
        <link href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">
        <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/Custom' %}"> -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/css/Custom.css' %}">

        <!-- Custom fonts for this template -->
        <link href="{% static 'vendor/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lora:400,700,400italic,700italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
        <link href="{% static 'css/clean-blog.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet">

      </head>

      <body>

    <!-- Navigation -->
    <div class="mynav">
      <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-info text-white"><strong> PERSONALITY LEADING </strong></div>
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light fixed-top" id="mainNav">
          <div class="container">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html"></a>
            <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
              Menu
              <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
            </button>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
              <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/home/">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/about/">About</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/services/">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="/contact/">Contact</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>


        <!-- Page Header -->
        <!-- <header class="masthead" style="background-image: url('img/contact-bg.jpg')"> -->
          <div class="overlay"></div>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div class="page-heading">
                  <h1>Contact Us</h1>
                  <span class="subheading">Have questions? I have answers.</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>


        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 text-dark mx-auto">
              <p>Want to get in touch? Fill out the form below to send us a message and We will get back to you as soon as possible!</p>
              <form name="sentMessage" id="contactForm" novalidate>
                <form action="" method="POST">

                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>Name</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" id="name" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your name.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>Email Address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" id="email" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your email address.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>
                    {{forms.emailid}}
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-group col-xs-12 floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>Phone Number</label>
                    <input type="tel" class="form-control" placeholder="Phone Number" id="phone" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter your phone number.">
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>

                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="control-group">
                  <div class="form-group floating-label-form-group controls">
                    <label>Message</label>
                    <textarea rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message" id="message" required data-validation-required-message="Please enter a message."></textarea>
                    <p class="help-block text-danger"></p>


                  </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div id="success"></div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="sendMessageButton" >Send</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div id="templatemo-contact">

                <p class="text-primary">

                  <h7><strong>Meet us<span> at our location</span> </strong></h7> </p> 
                <br>


                    <div class="contactHldr text-#0085a1">
                        <ul>


                              <strong>Personality Leading</strong><br>
                                (Online Jobs Guru Pvt.ltd)<br>
                                #169, 13th Main 1st Floor<br>
                                Aicoboo Nagar, 1st stage, BTM Layout<br>
                              Bangalore - 560029</p>
                              <h4>Locate us on Google maps</h4>
                              <a href="https://www.google.co.in/maps/place/Onlinejobsguru+Pvt.Ltd./@12.9167255,77.6087831,17z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x3bae14fc2c1a4461:0xa948622b989d82ff!8m2!3d12.9167203!4d77.6109718?hl=en"> <img src="{%static 'img/map.png' %}" width="150" height="114"><br>
                                <br>

                                <!-- <h5>Phone: 080 - 41250340</h5> -->
                            <p class="text-primary"><strong>Phone:</strong> 080 - 41250340</p>
                            <p class="text-light"><strong>Email:</strong> <br> <a href="mailto:info@personalityleading.com">info@personalityleading.com</a><br><a href="mailto:support@personalityleading.com">support@personalityleading.com</a></p>





        <hr>

        <!-- Footer -->
        <footer>
          <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <ul class="list-inline text-center">
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="https://twitter.com/onlinejobsguruu">
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-twitter fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/onlinejobsguru05/">
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-facebook fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </li>
                  <!-- <li class="list-inline-item">
                    <a href="#">
                      <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                        <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x"></i>
                        <i class="fa fa-github fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                      </span>
                    </a>
                  </li> -->
                </ul>
                <p class="copyright text-light">© 2016 PERSONALITY LEADING, ALL RIGHTS RESERVED</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </footer>

        <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript -->
        <script src="{% static 'vendor/jquery/jquery.min.js' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- Contact Form JavaScript -->
        <script src="{% static 'js/jqBootstrapValidation.j' %}"></script>
        <script src="{% static 'js/contact_me.js' %}"></script>

        <!-- Custom scripts for this template -->
        <script src="{% static 'js/clean-blog.min.js' %}"></script>

      </body>

    </html>
```

This is my forms.py

```
    from django import forms
    from .models import *

    class details_form(forms.ModelForm):
        name = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=100)
        emailid = forms.EmailField( required=True, max_length=250)
        phone = forms. CharField(max_length=11)
        message = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea())


        class Meta():
            model = user
            fields = ['name', 'emailid', 'phone', 'message']
```

How to establish connection between models and html fields. when I'm trying to add data in the fields the data is getting entered but not reflecting in the admin panel

Comment: You have to send post request and then received requested data and save into data base.

Comment: what changes i have to make in html file to connect my models in forms.py

Comment: Are you saving the form? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/

Comment: yes i am saving the form

Comment: Are the requests being sent valid? Check the status code of the responses or check for form errors. You should consider rendering the form using its builtin methods. e.g. `{{ form.as_p }}`. Your form inputs don't appear to have appropriate `name` attributes. You also don't have the CSRF token.

Comment: This question is from a brand new user, and it looks at least [related to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49421886/how-to-render-html-form-in-django), posted one hour before by another user. I am not sure if the questions are essentially duplicates, though.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML forms are not well-formed. You do not have the required CRSF token. Your form inputs also appear to be lacking the proper `name` attributes.

I would highly recommend rendering your form using the form's builtin methods, such as `{{ form.as_p }}`. This will ensure the form inputs are well-formed to the form class.